# split, export and read dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset, approximately 1 million rows, where various measurements occur for many objects. Each measurement is repeated for each object. My dataset looks a bit like this:

```
ID    time    measuremment1    measurement2    measurement3   
1     5       12              324            123
1     6       123             654            45
1     3       346             556            548
2     2       234             345            253
2     8       35              998            316
2     17      515             1005           323 
2     50      156             155            616
3     10      555             985            575
3     219     515             358            741
3     300     548             555            953
```

and so on...

I read the file in R using
    `read.csv`

what I want to do, is split and possibly export the dataset into individual csv files according to my object ID. In other words, I want individual csv files for each object. In addition, I would ideally like to re-read the files in R because I want to perform calculations.
I want to do this as an iterative process, typing a few lines in R so it will save me time.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: "using read.csv"...Don't do that to yourself. Use `fread` from `data.table`. It will be about 10x faster. Using `data.table` will speed up most of your operations with big data. There are a few minor drawbacks, but there are also a large number of benefits to `data.table` in addition to speed. Give it a try.

Comment: @Zheyuan Li yes I have around 1000 IDs

Comment: @Zheyuan Li yes it is sorted by ID first and then by time

Comment: @Zheyuan Li Unfortunately I am getting an error. I will try to look for what I am doing wrong, but an additional help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Zheyuan Li. yes all my data are stored in one single .csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption:**

1. Initially all your data is stored in a single, large file, "mydata.csv", and you read it in into R into a large data frame `dat`;
2. `dat` has been sorted by `ID`.

I have already checked with you that these conditions are satisfied.

I won't suggest using `split`, due to the size of your data frame. Instead, I suggest **a "read + write" iterative procedure for all `ID` subset**. We can use `skip` and `nrows` argument in `read.csv` to read a subset only.

---

We first determine number of cases for each `ID`:

```
x <- rle(dat$ID)  ## run length estimate
k <- x$lengths  ## number of cases for each ID
ID <- x$values  ## ID
```

Then we determine the rows where each `ID` chunk starts:

```
s <- c(0L, cumsum(k)) + 1L
```

We also store the column names of this data frame:

```
NAMES <- colnames(dat)
```

Then, we remove this large data frame `dat` from your R session, and perform "read + save" iteration for all `ID` chunks.

```
rm(dat); gc()
PATH <- getwd()

for (i in seq_along(ID)) {
  ## read in the data subset for the current `ID`
  tmp <- read.csv("mydata.csv", skip = s[i], nrows = k[i], header = FALSE)
  ## `write.csv` does not allow `col.names`, so we use `write.table`
  write.table(tmp, file = paste0(PATH,"/",ID[i],".csv"), row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",", col.names = NAMES)
  }
```

In each iteration, only a subset is read into R session so memory footprint is greatly reduced. You might want to customize file path `PATH`, as at the moment all files are stored into your working director `getwd()`.

---

Let's do a small test:

```
## example data frame
dat <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3,each=5), val=sample(15))
NAMES <- colnames(dat)
x <- rle(dat$ID)
k <- x$lengths
ID <- x$values
s <- c(0L, cumsum(k)) + 1L

## store it into a csv file
write.csv(dat, file = "mydata.csv", row.names = FALSE)

## iterative "read + write"
PATH <- getwd()
for (i in seq_along(ID)) {
  tmp <- read.csv("mydata.csv", skip = s[i], nrows = k[i], header = FALSE)
  write.table(tmp, file = paste0(PATH,"/",ID[i],".csv"), row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",", col.names = NAMES)
  }
```

After execution, I see three files: "1.csv", "2.csv" and "3.csv" in my working directory, each with desired data. So everything is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fastest and simplest way to do this is using `data.table`.

#### 1st: save subsets of the original data into separate `.csv` files

```
library(data.table)

set(df)[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("subset_", ID,".csv")), by = ID, .SDcols=names(df) ]
```

#### 2nd: fast read and bind multiple `.csv` files

```
# identify .csv files in the folder    
  filenames <- list.files( pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)

# read and rbind files
  df <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames, fread))
```